# How to make the ⇒ sign with Google Chart's TeX?

Tags: support, mathjax

I tried the following:

- `⇒` but I get $⇒$
- `\implies` but I get $\implies$
- `\Rightlongarrow` but I get $\Rightlongarrow$

Answer (score 3):

`\Rightarrow`, I think--I use [this online equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) when I don't know what TeX to use.

Also, just because `\xxx` shows up as `[\xxx?]` doesn't mean it's wrong, just that Google Charts doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's `\Rightarrow`: $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: I hate answering my own questions. :(